# Divergent subsequence of a divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, formal-proofs

If a real sequence $X$ is divergent, then does a divergent subsequence $X'\neq X$ exist.
I know how to prove this for a specific limit. That is if X does not converge to L then there exist a subsequence X' not equal to X such that X' does not converge to L. How do i extrapolate from here?

Comment: What constraint do you have that prevents you from just taking $X'$ to be $X$? or $X$ with finitely many elements deleted?

Comment: Yeah!! I forgot about the m-tail. Thanks @GregMartin